# Wordpress Help: Make first post full text, the rest excerpts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make my WP theme show the full text of the first post, and just excerpts for the remaining posts on the homepage. When I implement the below, it shows all posts as excerpts, including the first post.

Here's the code for index.php...

```
 $some_number = 0; 
 if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 $some_number++;
```

Here is the code for post-homepage.php...

```
<p>
<?php
    global $some_number;
    if($some_number == 1) {
        the_content(); }
    else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
 ?>
 </p>
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing $some_number within the loop. Just move it before the loop:

```
$some_number = 0; 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
     $some_number++;
```

Otherwise, it will reset the variable for each post.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier and again now just to double check, but didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried just echoing $some_number to see what's going on?

Comment: I just tried to `echo "number is $some_number";` and does not show up if I place it after `if($some_number == 1)`. When I place it after the else statement, I get `number is` with $some_number being blank.

Comment: Looks like a scope issue. Try this: global $some_number = 0; I don't know if that's a proper or safe thing to do, but it may work.

Comment: Added global, and got this error: `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'`    Also, I updated the OP to include the themes template.php, which may have something going on there.

Comment: Sorry, declare global in the included file before echoing (in post.php):     global $some_number; echo $some_number;

Comment: Ahh... my bad. Ok, so now when used after the else statement, placed before the_excerprt I get `1` on the first post, `2` on the second, etc. So at least it recognizes that it's the first post. Seems though it should show up only after the 2nd post... and not sure why it doesn't work on the if statement for the first post. For some reason it just won't cooperate. Something in the template.php or functions.php maybe?

Comment: I would put the echo outside the if statement to see what is being received for every post. functions.php shouldn't interfere with something so simple.

Comment: Ok, weird thing happened... I put the echo outside the if statement like you suggested, and now it works properly. The first post is the full text, followed by excerpts. Each post lists their respective number before the post... 1, next post is 2, etc. So how do I fix this from here? If I just put `global $some_number` before the if statement, is that bad? Seems to fix this issue. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Also... I just noticed that if I got to the next page, it shows the full text of the first post on that page, and excerpts for the rest. I was hoping this would only occur on the homepage.

Comment: Yes. I should have been clearer. You need to declare the variable as global before you use it, so before the if. As for the pagination, you would need to add $paged to your if statement. Echo $paged to see what value you get on each page (I'm not sure what value you get on the first page, but on subsequent it gives you the page number).

Comment: on the first page, $paged displays 0. So how would that look exactly? I tried...    `global $some_number;
   if($some_number == 1 || $paged == 0) {
    the_content();}
   else {
    the_excerpt();}`

Comment: Got it... `if($some_number == 1 && !is_paged())`